# crystal reports RCAPI

Tags: java, crystal-reports

Is there is a way to display the data in specified format using RCAPI.

Pls find the code below.

```
ReportClientDocument boReportClientDocument = new ReportClientDocument();
        boReportClientDocument.open("blankreport.rpt", 0);

public void displayReportData(ReportClientDocument document,ISection detailArea) {
        int INSERT_AT_END = -1;
        DBUtil dBUtil = new DBUtil();
        Field field = null;
        Fields fields = null;
        FieldObject boFieldObject = null;
        try {
            document.getDatabaseController().addDataSource(dBUtil.getData());
           // ISection detailArea = document.getReportDefController().getReportDefinition().getDetailArea().getSections().get(0);
            Tables tables = document.getDatabaseController().getDatabase().getTables();
            for (int i = 0; i < tables.size(); i++) {
             fields = tables.getTable(i).getDataFields();
             int leftInc = 0;
             int topInc =0;
             System.out.println("no of records   iiii::::" + i);
             for (int j = 0; j < fields.size(); j++) {
             System.out.println("no of records   jjjj::::" + j);
             field = (Field) fields.get(j);
             boFieldObject = new FieldObject();
             boFieldObject.setDataSource(field.getFormulaForm());
             boFieldObject.setFieldValueType(field.getType());
             boFieldObject.setLeft(250 +leftInc);
             boFieldObject.setTop(800);
             boFieldObject.setWidth(3);
            boFieldObject.setHeight(250);
            // leftInc += 30;
             //topInc += 50;
             document.getReportDefController().getReportObjectController().add(boFieldObject,detailArea,-1);
             }
             }


        } catch (ReportSDKException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Report.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide more info in the question: Which data? And in which format?

Comment: For example, data from database table like CUSTOMER. I looking to display the CUSTOMER table data like customerid, customername, address. As the columns of the table would be headers of the report, data for the columns should display in tabular format.